# Are phase transitions in one-dimensional random-field Ising model possible?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, ising-model, randomness

Translationally invariant one-dimensional models, with interactions of finite range and a finite number of states at the site, don't allow phase transitions at positive temperatures. This fact is a simple consequence of the Perron-Frobenius theorem and relations between partition functions and transfer matrices.

For the random-field Ising model (RFIM), the partition function is not equal to the trace of some degree of the transfer matrix. So the simple argument about the non-existence of phase transition, which was valid in a spatially uniform situation, doesn't apply in the case of the random field. My question is the following. Are there any known non-existence theorems for the phase transitions at a non-zero temperature in the RFIM in one dimension?

This question is due to the rich diversity of interesting properties of the RFIM at zero temperature, even in one dimension. For some distributions of a random field, the ground state of 1d RFIM can have macroscopic degeneracy. There also can be discontinuities in the magnetization.

Update. I want to try to clarify my question more because of comments by Connor Behan and Roger Vadim. I know about the Imry-Ma argument. As far as I understand, this argument is about ferromagnetic ordering. My question is more general. In the ground state of 1d RFIM, spins tend to make clusters of different sizes and probabilities. Changes in model parameters lead to changes in cluster formation. Changes in cluster formation lead to discontinuities in some physical quantities which look like they can exist at finite temperatures. Hence my question. It is not about ferromagnetic transition, it is about the principal possibility of different phase transitions of the first kind. And my question is not about phase transitions in translationally invariant Ising model with long-range interaction like in [this topic](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/634434/finite-range-1d-ising-model-vs-infinite-range-ising-model).

The energy of 1d RFIM is
$$
E(\{\sigma\}) = -J\sum_{j} \sigma_j \sigma_{j+1} - \sum_j h_j \sigma_j.
$$
Here $h_j$ are frozen (quenched) fields generated according to some distribution. It is improbable for any nontrivial distribution that $h_j = h_{j+1}$ for all $j$. Hence RFIM is not translationally invariant. Configurations $\{\sigma\}$ and $\{\sigma'\}$, where $\sigma_j' = \sigma_{j+1}$, have different energies.

Comment: I checked the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.01617 and the introduction says there is no phase transition for $d \leq 2$. It cites the Imry-Ma criterion for this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finite range 1D Ising model vs. infinite range Ising model](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/634434/finite-range-1d-ising-model-vs-infinite-range-ising-model)

Comment: @ConnorBehan Thank you. I've updated my quaestion.

Comment: @RogerVadim No, it does not. I tried to clarify my question.

Comment: @Gec I think the answer by IvanVelenik and his comments are quite good, as well as their other answer that they link to.

Comment: @RogerVadim IvanVilenik gave a good answer to your question. But your question and his answer are about translationally invariant models. My question is about models with random fields. Such models do not possess translational invariance in the strong sense that energy doesn't change when the spin configuration is changed like $\sigma_j' = \sigma_{j+1}$.

Comment: I don't see what kind of phase transition you are hoping for. Correlations will decay exponentially fast at all positive temperatures, so that no long-range structures can emerge. Of course, the $T=0$ situation is very different from this perspective. Could you explain in more detail what you're looking for?

Comment: Note also that the uniqueness theorems for one-dimensional systems (for instance, the very general Theorem (8.39) in [Georgii's book](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9783110250329/html)) do not require translation invariance, just a sufficiently fast decay of the interactions (in particular, they obviously hold in the nearest-neighbor case).

Comment: @YvanVelenik I don't know the mathematical theory of phase transitions. In particular, I don't understand if the uniqueness of Gibbs measure means the continuous differentiability of the quenched free energy $f(\theta, h) = -\theta\ lim_{N\to\infty} \overline{\ln Z}/N$ with respect to $\theta$ and $h$.  In thermodynamics, phase transitions are defined through the differentiability properties of free energy. I have reasons to think that, for some random field distributions, discontinuities of quenched free energy derivatives present at zero temperature persist at nonzero temperatures.

Comment: Yes uniqueness implies continuous derivatives. Of course, it does not preclude higher-order singularities. In translation-invariant one-dimensional systems, it is known that the free energy is always analytic, even when long-range interactions are present (not of *too* long range, of course, otherwise you get ordering). I do not recall having seen results of similar flavor for disordered systems, but I am not so familiar with this literature.

Comment: @YvanVelenik, Is the last statement true for the quenched free energy regardless of the distribution of the random field? Even in cases where the pdf has discontinuities?

Comment: Yes, I think so (if by "last statement" you refer to the one about uniqueness). Continuity of the pdf should be irrelevant: the main reason you have uniqueness is that in short-range 1d systems information cannot travel over macroscopic distances: in the nearest-neighbor case, any "error" that occurs at a vertex completely decouples the spins on both sides. That's the reason structures cannot become macroscopic in 1d. (As a side note, let me point out that disorder has usually a tendency of smoothing, or even removing, the phase transitions present in homogeneous systems.)

Comment: @YvanVelenik Thank you very much. For some particular distribution of random field, I see that function $f(h) = \lim_{\theta\to0} C(\theta, h)/\theta$, where $C$ is heat capacity, has discontinuity at some particular value of $h$. From here, I deduced that there should be a line of discontinuity of entropy in this model. Now I see that I am probably wrong.